# Gravity form notification not sending

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

https://i.stack.imgur.com/grDME.png
Without filling the conditional fields email notification not sending to the admin. But when I fill up all the fields even non-required fields then working email notification send to the admin. Please help me, guys.

Comment: please attached screen short of gravity form